# What is the best alternative to FILTER if you need to have multiple rows for the condtion?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that looks like this:

[image]

I would like to be able to return all results from row 1 given a criteria from the data in B2:G7. For example, if I wanted "Grass" from the above sheet, the results would be:

[image]

I have tried to do this with FILTER, but it requires the condition be limited to one row or column. What would be the best alternative?

Example sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/110De2u6mKLT7SOTfaXN6EZVqgD35pEeeog9o5WWn5bs

Comment: How would you feel about =split(TEXTJOIN(",",1,if(countif(B2:B,"Grass"),B1,""),if(countif(C2:C,"Grass"),C1,""),if(countif(D2:D,"Grass"),D1,""),if(countif(E2:E,"Grass"),E1,""),if(countif(F2:F,"Grass"),F1,""),if(countif(G2:G,"Grass"),G1,"")),",")?

Comment: The issue with that is that the sheet I need this for has thousands of rows and columns, so to input each one would be extremely time-consuming. Thank you though!

Comment: or how would you feel about transposing the data, say later in this sheer  (with =Transpose, nothing manual) and then saying something like =query(A11:G16,"select A where (B='Grass') or (C='Grass') or (D='Grass') or (E='Grass') or (F='Grass') or (G='Grass')")?

Comment: Ok, so scratch that, too.

Comment: It would still be painful, but if you had =if(countif(B2:B7, "Grass"),B1,"") at the foot of column B, you could drag that formula right, and then textjoin/split just that row using a range

Comment: On the Jeremy Help? tab of your example I showed how my idea works with entering 2 short formulas and dragging one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added a new sheet ("Erik Help") to your sample spreadsheet. Enter a search word in A2. The results will be returned beginning in C2 and filling rightward.

The C2 formula:

`=IFERROR(FILTER(Sheet1!B1:G1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TRIM(A2),QUERY(Sheet1!B2:G,,ROWS(Sheet1!B2:G))))),"NO MATCHES")`

The important piece here is the `QUERY`. While most people know that the final parameter of a `QUERY` can be set to 0 or 1 to signify how many header rows to return, the actual number of rows that can be returned in the header is not limited to 0 or 1. So if we ask `QUERY` to return no selected data in a "Select" clause and yet set the header parameter to the number of data rows, headers for each column wind up being a column-by-column mash-up of the data from each row in each column.

This we *can* use with `FILTER`, as you can see.